# All locale getting bundled into one using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, momentjs

In my react / webpack project I am using `ContextReplacementPlugin` to bundle locale files which I need -

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /de|fr|hu/)  ]
};
```

This code is bundling file correctly, but my only concerns is that its bundling all locale files currently and in future we need to support another countries and at that time bundle size keeps growing.

Is thr any way with which I can keep my bundle size in control and bundle only that locale which user will use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bundle only the locale which the user will use. Consider the timelines of these two separate events:

- When you bundle, no one knows about this version of the application but you, there *is* no user
- When a user logs in, you've bundled the application probably long before they've logged in (you would have had to, or else, what else are they logging into?)

You need to bundle all possible locales any user may need to use upfront, so if there is only a subset of locales you will use, bundle those and that is the most you can optimize your bundle.

As for keeping bundle size under control, I recommend using the [`webpack-bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)